# Change Hyperlink color (inside of a col)

Tags: bootstrap-5

I'm trying to remove the "text-decoration" of a hyperlink and change the color in Bootstrap, all i have is this:

```
 <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 col-lg-3">
        <a href="Container.html">Container</a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-12 col-lg-3"><a href="grid.html">Grid</a></div>
      <div class="col-12 col-lg-3"><a href="Columns.html">Columns</a></div>
      <div class="col-12 col-lg-3"><a href="Gutter.html">Gutter</a></div>
    </div>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think all you want to do can be found on Bootstrap 5 documentation. All you need to do it just to search on the search bar.

Text decoration: you can add class "text-decoration-none" on tag "a" to remove the underline
while for color, you can refer to https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/helpers/colored-links/

you can see how to use it and find sample there.